# Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.1.5-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.5) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1)

I'm trying to integrate the Carrot Quest library and I'm facing a dependency conflict problem.

I tried to do exclude group, but without success

`

```
implementation ('io.carrotquest:android-sdk:1.0.60-commonRelease') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
}
```

`

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this issue?